# Show Cambodia Currency Symbol with unicode character in Android Device

Tags: android, unicode, textview, symbols

I want to show cambodia currency symbol in my android device

```
TextView mTextView;

String getSymbol="\u17DB";
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
  mTextView.setText("Symbol "+getSymbol);
 }
```

when I run above code in 2.3 device it give me output like
[image]

when I run above code in 4.0 device it give me output like
[image]

So any idea how can i sole it ?

Comment: For Android under 5.0 is not support Khmer Unicode ( Cambodia ) .